# How to send a local notification for all devices above API Level 16?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am able to send notifications from firebase to the devices . But i need to send notification to same device locally.I am using oreo version mobile.
I tried using this code :

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"150");

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Hearty365")
            .setContentTitle("Default notification")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentInfo("Info");


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can create a **notification channel**:

```
CharSequence name = getString(R.string.notification_channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.notification_channel_description);
            int importance  = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager1 = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

Then use the notification channel to **send a notification** (remember to save your NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_canceledrantevu)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_add_busy_title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_add_busy_msga))
                .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000})
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
```

Keep in mind that it is mandatory to create a notification channel if you want to show notifications in devices with API level >= Version.Oreo

Answer (score 3):

> Android-O Includes Notification Channels

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int notifyId = 1;
String channelId = "some_channel_id";

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setContentTitle("Some Message")
        .setContentText("You've received new messages!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setChannel(channelId)
        .build();

notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

> Notification Channels

Notification Channels provide us with the ability to group the notifications that our application sends into manageable groups. Once our notifications are in these channels, we no longer have input into their functionality — so it is up to the user to manage these channels. When it comes to altering the settings for our application notifications, the user will be presented with these options:

Starting from the left, you can see in the first screen that the notification settings for our app displays the notification settings for our application. From here the user can:

Block all notification channels for our app. This means that notifications from our application will never be shown on the users device
If supported, the user can state whether or not our applications notifications should be shown as badges on the Home app
The notification categories that exist for our application. From here the user can toggle these to be enabled or disabled
The next screen (in the middle) can be accessed once the user selects a notification category from the first screen. From here the user is able to:

Block all notifications from our app that come from this channel
Display notifications from this channel within the Home app, if supported
And as shown in the final screenshot, the user can also set the importance of notifications from this channel. The option selected here will state how they want to be prompted when a notification is received.

We also have the ability to group notification channels into separate groups. This is so that we are able to have the same notification channels across multiple application modes.

For example, my application may support Personal and Business mode, or Child and Parent mode — this allows us to give the option to manage notification settings across multiple groups.

These are displayed in the same place as our notification channels, except just separated into their corresponding group.

On older versions of Android (pre-O) these new features will be completely ignored, so we don’t have to worry about current implementations breaking.

Now we know a little more about what notification channels are, I think it’s time we look at how we can implement them into our application!

[Exploring Android O: Notification Channels](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c)